# SELECT statement based on OneToMany relation and dates

Tags: sql, oracle

**Overview:**

I have these beans in my hbm files. First is a report with two dates (start and stop of report) and a list of excluded periods. Second is keeping excluded periods for report. Report is turned off during these excluded periods.

```
<class name="com.company.Report" table="TReport">
    <property name="startDate" column="m_StartDate" type="timestamp"/>
    <property name="endDate" column="m_EndDate" type="timestamp"/>
    <list name="excludedPeriods" table="TExcludedPeriod" inverse="true" lazy="false">
        <key column="m_TReport" not-null="true"/>
        <list-index column="m_ListIndex" base="1"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.company.ExcludedPeriod"/>
    </list>
</class>
<class name="com.company.ExcludedPeriod" table="TExcludedPeriod">
    <id column="m_Id" name="id" />
    <many-to-one name="report" class="com.company.JobsReport" column="m_TJobReport" not-null="true" />
    <property name="index" column="m_ListIndex" type="integer"/>
    <property name="start" column="m_Start" type="timestamp"/>
    <property name="stop" column="m_Stop" type="timestamp"/>
</class>
```

**Task:**

Select all reports that are turned on during a selected period of time (defined by `startPeriod` and `endPeriod`).

**My code:**

```
SELECT * FROM treport r LEFT OUTER JOIN texcludedperiod ep ON r.m_id=ep.m_treport
WHERE NOT (ep.m_id IS NOT NULL AND (ep.m_start>=startPeriod AND ep.m_end<=endPeriod));
```

**Problem:**

It is working if there is no excluded period for a report or there is only one such a period, but in other cases it selects reports that shouldn't be selected. Consider this example (d/m/yyyy format):

> Report: start 1/1/2000, stop 1/2/2000, excluded periods:
>   7/1/2000-10/1/2000, 12/1/2000-15/1/2000
>
> Searched period: startPeriod 8/1/2000, stopPeriod 9/1/2000.

This report shouldn't be selected.

Comment: My brain stops at where not...
Does that translate into :  where (ep.m_id is null or (ep.m_start < startperiod and ep.m_end > endperiod)) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those cases where you should use a NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
  FROM treport r
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM texcludedperiod ep 
                      WHERE ep.m_treport = r.m_id AND
                            ep.m_start >= startPeriod AND
                            ep.m_end <= endPeriod);
```

Basically you're saying "Give me all the reports where there are no exclusions during the reporting period in question".

Comment: I need opposite inequalities, but this is it, thanks. Now I have to translate this into Hibernate Criteria :D